# read multiple file from folder

Tags: matlab, fopen

I want to read multiple files from a folder but this code does not work properly:

```
   direction=dir('data');

    for i=3:length(direction)

        Fold_name=strcat('data\',direction(i).name);

            filename = fullfile(Fold_name);
            fileid= fopen(filename);
            data = fread (fileid)';
    end
```

Comment: Does not read all the files, i can get only last file after reading

Comment: @lighting that is, because I assume it just overwrites the `data` variable on every iteration

Comment: so if i want to calculate  specific values for all the files and just get those in the end what should i do?

Comment: Have an array of data to read things into - or do the processing in a loop and put the answer into a array/matrix

Comment: @doctorlove I did, for example i want to calculate the variance for all those files and store them in a matrix but i get only last files variance.

Comment: Do the calculations inside the loop, and save the results of each iteration in  a different place on the array, or on different dimension of the matrix. At the end you will have all the results saved.

Comment: @Adiel Exactly, my problem is i don't know how can i save the results of each iteration on the array.

Comment: Would some code showing how to put several different results into a vector hlep?

Comment: I hope so, or should i put my code here so you can see the problem?

Comment: For example: `data=fread (fileid)';` `result(i)=mean(data);`. After all the iterations, you'll get a vector named `result`, with the means of all the data that you read. Each element of the vector corresponds to one file.

Comment: Yeah, it's work. Thanks!

Comment: Also do not use `strcat` for creating paths since it trims whitespace. You should always use `fullfile` to concatenate folder and filenames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of getting access to all the files after reading:

```
direction=dir('data');

        for i=3:length(direction)

            Fold_name=strcat('data\',direction(i).name);

                filename = fullfile(Fold_name);
                fileid(i)= fopen(filename);
                data{i-2} = fread (fileid(i))';
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your algorithm to make it easier

Just use this form :

folder='address\datafolder\'    ( provide your folder address where data is located)

then:
filenames=dir([folder,'*.txt']);  ( whatever your data format is, you can specify it in case you have other files you do not want to import, in this example, i used .txt format files)

for k = 1 : numel(filenames)

Do your code

end

It should work. It's a much more efficient method, as it can apply to any folder without you worrying about names, number order etc... Unless you want to specify certain files with the same format within the folder. I would recommend you to use a separate folder to put your files in.

Comment: When i'm trying to use `fileid = fopen(filenames); data = fread (fileid)'; ` in that loop i get this error " Error using fopen.
First input must be a file name of type char, or a file identifier of type double."

Comment: @Patrick, you have to specify which file you work in each iteration.